# Spring MVC: HTTP 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported when making POST request

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

Just started a default Spring MVC project, and I'm not able to get the POST requests handler to work. This is my controller:

```
package com.myapp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.myapp.domain.Response;

@Controller
public class MyAppController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Response query() {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Response is a simple POJO like this:

```
package com.myapp.domain;

public class Response {

    private String text;
    private String ref;

    public Response() {}

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />



</beans:beans>
```

Jackson is declared as a dependency in pom.xml.

When I make a POST request (through Postman), tomcat returns `HTTP 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported`. Is there any configuration to get tomcat responding to POST requests?

Comment: you are not making a post request, or have the url/parameters wrong

Comment: you are making GET request

Comment: It looks like the client makes a `GET` and not a `POST` request

Comment: Create a simple HTML form and post the request

Comment: This is the request the client is doing `POST /gowex HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 636a3b05-db9d-d1f1-a08c-e395bb38b7ac`

Comment: I tried writing a GET request handler in controller, and the same Post request returns the GET handler response, an HTML page

Comment: Spring doesn't convert post requests to get. Your problem lies elsewhere ... *these are the not the bugs you are looking for*

Comment: Ok, it seems it's not possible to make POST requests to the root (`"/"`) path of a spring web app. Changing the @RequestMapping value to `"/query"` apparently solves the problem

Comment: @bolloyo thats not true, you can make a post request to root, if you have set it up correctly.

Comment: @NimChimpsky could you provide those settings as an answer? I've started with default settings for a Spring mvc project in STS

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080
```

to check.

Or try to set another url for your test, not the '/'.